Bash & comparator
just got a little question as I don't find an answer via google. What is the result of the "& 7" comparator?
# print the number of the current rootfs
get_rootfs() {
    dev=$(stat -c %d /)
    case $((dev & 7)) in
        2) echo 1 ;;
        3) echo 2 ;;
    esac
}

Already tried in console, but nothing is echoed, no matter which number instead of 7 i use.

Try this: for i in {0..24};do echo $i $((i&7));done and read man -Pless\ +/bitwise bash.
